# Плагин для vim на С(++)

Tags: c++, c, dll, плагин, vim

Нужен пример colorer-плагина для vim написанного на С(++)

Для win32 -- в виде .dll собранного mingw32 для этой сборки вима: http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

Или хотя бы просто исходник простейшего vim-плагина на С(++) в .dll

Comment: на аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном SO указали на фичу vim channel